# Flutter: Dynamic Height of Widgets must be multiple of a given number

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The widgets have different heights, that are **dynamic**.
I need the height to be a **multiple** of 20, so it fits in the grid I created.

Is there a possibility to force the widgets to increase their height by 20 pixels at a time if they need to expand?

In othe words I need it to snap to a grid I pre defined.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TreeNode extends StatelessWidget {
  const TreeNode({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.minSize,
    required this.maxSize,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final int minSize, maxSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 400
            ? minSize.toDouble()
            : maxSize.toDouble(),
        height: 200, // needs to be changed
        child: Visibility(
          visible: true,
          child: child,
          maintainSize: true,
          maintainState: true,
          maintainAnimation: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help. Example of how it looks now:
[image]

**EDIT:**
I figured it out.
For anybody else who has a similar Problem.

I used IntrinsicWidth() with stepHeight and stepWidth
It may be quite expensive to do, but it fits my needs.

**New Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TreeNode extends StatelessWidget {
  const TreeNode({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.minSize,
    required this.maxSize,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final int minSize, maxSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntrinsicWidth(
      stepHeight: 20,
      stepWidth: 20,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 400
            ? minSize.toDouble()
            : maxSize.toDouble(),
        child: Visibility(
          visible: false,
          child: child,
          maintainSize: true,
          maintainState: true,
          maintainAnimation: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer, consider avoiding the IntrinsicWidth approach if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To add 20 px:** `height + 20.0;`

**To multiply** just add a factor of your choice (can also be dynamic): `height * 1.5` or `height * dynamicFactor`.

If you want do to it **conditionally**, you can add a boolean `shouldMultiply` and use it to toggle like this: `givenValue * (shouldMultiply ? 20 : 1)`;

**Using your code example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TreeNode extends StatelessWidget {
  const TreeNode({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.minSize,
    required this.maxSize,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final int minSize, maxSize;
  final factor = 1.15; // +15%
  bool requiresFactor; // Either change this via method you define and hook up to
                       // the ontap handler of a gesture detector (which can wrap your FittedBox),

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 400
            ? minSize.toDouble()
            : maxSize.toDouble(),
        height: 200 + (requiresFactor ? 20.0 : 0.0),
        // or height: 200 * (shouldMultiply ? factor : 1),
        child: Visibility(
          visible: true,
          child: child,
          maintainSize: true,
          maintainState: true,
          maintainAnimation: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit (as the OP figured out correctly):**
The [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) class can be used to snap to a multiple of the stepWidth or stepHeight with their respective properties to be set to a non-null value.
**[WARNING:]**
However, as the docs warn you "This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. **Avoid using it where possible.**". Hence, you should consider writing your own simplified "work-around" logic for your case, as this class is not really necessary here.
So, definitely try it out - if you find an obstacle update your question, comment me and I´ll try my best to help you out :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I think my question was a bit confusing to read.  I tried to clear it up a bit, by rewriting it.

I don't want to set the height myself, but rather let the widget itself determine its size. But I want to force it to expand by 20 pixels at a time.